# Add a class to an element with Nokogiri

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

Apparently Nokogiri's [`add_class`](http://nokogiri.rubyforge.org/nokogiri/Nokogiri/XML/NodeSet.html#M000264) method only works on `NodeList`s, making this code invalid:

```
doc.search('a').each do |anchor|
  anchor.inner_text = "hello!"
  anchor.add_class("whatever") # WHOOPS!
end
```

What can I do to make this code work? I figured it'd be something like

```
doc.search('a').each do |anchor|
  anchor.inner_text = "hello!"
  Nokogiri::XML::NodeSet.new(anchor).add_class("whatever")
end
```

but this doesn't work either. Please tell me I don't have to implement my own `add_class` for single nodes!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A CSS class is just another attribute on an element:

```
doc.search('a').each do |anchor|
  anchor.inner_text = "hello!"
  anchor['class']="whatever"
end
```

Since CSS classes are space-delimited in the attribute, if you're not sure if one or more classes might already exist you'll need something like

```
anchor['class'] ||= ""
anchor['class'] = anchor['class'] << " whatever"
```

You need to explicitly set the attribute using `=` instead of just mutating the string returned for the attribute. This, for example, will not change the DOM:

```
anchor['class'] ||= ""
anchor['class'] << " whatever"
```

Even though it results in more work being done, I'd probably do this like so:

```
class Nokogiri::XML::Node
  def add_css_class( *classes )
    existing = (self['class'] || "").split(/\s+/)
    self['class'] = existing.concat(classes).uniq.join(" ")
  end
end
```

If you don't want to monkey-patch the class, you could alternatively:

```
module ClassMutator
  def add_css_class( *classes )
    existing = (self['class'] || "").split(/\s+/)
    self['class'] = existing.concat(classes).uniq.join(" ")
  end
end

anchor.extend ClassMutator
anchor.add_css_class "whatever"
```

**Edit**: You can see that this is basically what Nokogiri does internally for the `add_class` method you found by clicking on the class to view the source:

```
# File lib/nokogiri/xml/node_set.rb, line 136
def add_class name
  each do |el|
    next unless el.respond_to? :get_attribute
    classes = el.get_attribute('class').to_s.split(" ")
    el.set_attribute('class', classes.push(name).uniq.join(" "))
  end
  self
end
```

Answer (score 3):

Nokogiri's `add_class`, works on a NodeSet, like you found. Trying to add the class inside the `each` block wouldn't work though, because at that point you are working on an individual node.

Instead:

```
require 'nokogiri'

html = '<p>one</p><p>two</p>'
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(html)

doc.search('p').tap{ |ns| ns.add_class('boo') }.each do |n|
  puts n.text
end
puts doc.to_html
```

Which outputs:

```
# >> one
# >> two
# >> <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
# >> <html><body>
# >> <p class="boo">one</p>
# >> <p class="boo">two</p>
# >> </body></html>
```

The `tap` method, implemented in Ruby 1.9+, gives access to the nodelist itself, allowing the `add_class` method to add the "boo" class to the `<p>` tags.

Comment: Why can't you just do `doc.search('p').add_class('boo').each do ...`

Comment: You can use `doc = Nokogiri::HTML.fragment(html)` if you don't want Nokogiri to add the doctype and other html and body tags

Answer (score 2):

Old thread, but it's the top Google hit. You can now do this with the [`append_class` method](https://nokogiri.org/rdoc/Nokogiri/XML/NodeSet#append_class-instance_method) without having to mess with space-delimiters:

```rb
doc.search('a').each do |anchor|
  anchor.inner_text = "hello!"
  anchor.append_class('whatever')
end
```